# Как включить radio при нажатии в любое место сайта

Tags: калькулятор

Здравствуйте.
Есть форма калькулятора. В ней должны быть обязательные radio.
Т.е. среди кучи чекбоксов и радио, нужно чтобы были включены несколько radio.

Например форма:

```
<form method="POST" name="calc_form" action="" sourceindex="1">
<input id="i_box_0" type="checkbox" name="i_box_0" onclick="check_event(false)" sourceindex="2">
<input id="i_radio_2" type="radio" value="12" name="i_radio_0" onclick="check_event(false)" sourceindex="4">
<input id="i_box_1" type="checkbox" name="i_box_1" onclick="check_event(false)" sourceindex="3">
</form>
```

Надо чтобы после загрузки страницы, были автоматом выбраны несколько radio или чекбоксов, например **i_radio_0** и **i_box_1**.
Чтобы они выбирались на событие: **нажатие в любую часть страницы мышкой**.
Не на загрузку страницы, а именно нажатие в любое место мышкой.

**Пример использования формы в жизни:** Форма для подсчёта стоимости сайта, вот в ней будут обязательные параметры уже выбраны. Например CMS и форма обратной связи. Т.е. они всегда присутствуют при формировании цены.

Comment: Отключил сейчас noconflict.js - не помогло :-(

Comment: А меня "улыбают" такие вопросы от студии, которая собирается делать сайты :) Страшно становится за свою профессию....

Comment: мне страшно, правда...

Comment: Это видно) напихать кучу скриптов, а потом не понимать почему не срабатывает текущий скрипт, да :)

Comment: Ты я вижу только гадить пришёл?
Не помогаешь, так хоть не мешай.

Comment: $('body').click(function() {
          alert('body clicked');
    });

начните с малого :)   

зыж посмотрел исходный код... это ппц полный... ВНЕЗАПНО ближе к концу страницы `<body onLoad="captcha();">`, в конце страницы ВДРУГ `<style></style>`... Вы чего творите? Я уж молчу, что подключено помимо jquery еще и mootools, которое вполне может конфликтовать между собой... Поэтому совет: приведите шаблон в порядок, иначе там можно до бесконечности копаться. И еще почитайте для чего нужен nocoflicts.js, а так же как работать с JQuery если подключены походие библиотеки, которые перехватывают $

Comment: Это в калькуляторе (делал не я), косяк с <body>. Попробую убрать, но там капец как всё коряво(в калькуляторе этом).
А вот <style> это я воткнул, чтобы переписывать стили только на тех страницах на которых надо, а не во всём сайте. Работает и не конфликтует.
Я в принципе решил проблему, обошёл функциями калькулятора.
Будет время, пороюсь. Ща надо остальное делать, сайт запускать. А то старая версия мне вообще не нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать функцию click для клика на теге body

```
$('body').click(function() {
      $('#i_box_0, #i_radio_2').prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ky27h/12/

или на теге html

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('#i_box_0, #i_radio_2').prop('checked', true);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/ky27h/14/

Comment: Тут на сайте я увидел, что это всё работает. Но не понял как точно реализовать на своём сайте.
Я так понял, что тут есть jquery, не проблема, мой сайт на Joomla, поэтому там есть jquery.
Пожалуйста, дайте полностью код страницы от <html> до </html>
А то я уже и так и сяк попробовал, не срабатывает.
Сильно не ругайте, я не профи.

Comment: Как-то так http://pastebin.com/Lb4h7r6S

Comment: Вроде всё правильно сделал, но не работает. точнее на простенькой форме как тут на сайте - работает. стоит применить в мою на моём сайте, перестаёт срабатывать. Посмотрите пожалуйста, вот ссыль: http://new.sozdaem-saity.ru/price.html
Подключены (jquery-1.8.3.min.js) и ниже ваш скрипт (calc-checked.js)
Я там поменял переменные чекбокса одного.
Но результата нет :-(

Comment: Скрипт срабатывает на id, а не на имя, у вас не задано никакого id для этого инпута.  
`<input type="checkbox" name="xz_1" value="1000" class="" aria-invalid="false">`

Comment: Спасибо. Буду править скрипт калькулятора, чтобы добавить ID ко всем и вся :-)
Большое спасибо. Как доделаю, обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: Добавил ко всем ID, вот что получилось:
<input type="checkbox" id="xz_1" name="xz_1" value="1000">
Но так и не работает :-(
НЕ смертельно конечно, но так хотелось...

Comment: Попробуйте убрать jquery-noconflict.js из подключенных скриптов <script src="/media/zen/js/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

<body><lable for="id твоего радио">
....
</lable></body>

Comment: не понял?!